# Maximize sum of absolute real parts of complex numbers

Tags: math, language-agnostic, complex-numbers

Assuming complex numbers *a1..an*, what is the angle *phi* those numbers have to be rotated by (= multiplied by exp(i*phi) ) to maximize the sum of the absolute value of the real parts?

```
in:=complex[N]
out:=in.*exp(i*phi)
f:=sum(abs(real(out)))
```

-> which phi maximizes f?

Is there a elegant solution (As in not iterating over phi) ?

It is not difficult to find the angle each number has to be multiplied by to make it real, but weighting those angles to find a single optimal one for all of them is difficult, because the rotation is obviously not linear - something like

```
sum(phiN.*abs(in))/sum(abs(in))
```

does not work (produces lower sum than with an angle found by iterating over -pi to pi)

Any ideas are appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there exists an analytic solution, it is usually too hard to calculate it (may be feasible for a small number of input variables (`n`)). I'll first go over this solution, then suggest alternatives.

### Analytic solution

Given the input numbers `(l1, phi1), (l2, phi2), ... (ln, phin)`, where `li` is the length and `phii` the angle of the number, you want to find:

```
arg max_phi Sum_i abs(li cos(phii + phi))
```

You only have one independent variable. So, we start by deriving the function with respect to `phi`:

```
f'(phi) = Sum_i (-li sin(phii + phi) * abs'(l cos(phii + phi))
```

`abs'(x)` is either `+1` or `-1`. Due to its discontinuity, we won't get around trying every combination. So you end up with `2^n` variants of `f'`. The optimum is then one of the (usually four) arguments where `f'(phi)=0`. This can be calculated as follows. I denote with `si` the sign of the i-th term, which you need to modify:

```
numerator = Sum_i si li sin(phii)
denominator = (Sum_i li^2) + (Sum_i Sum_{j>i} 2 * li * lj * si * sj
```

cos(phii - phij))

Then, the four solution candidates are:

```
phi*    = -arc cos( numerator / sqrt(denominator))
phi**   = -arc cos(-numerator / sqrt(denominator))
phi***  =  arc cos( numerator / sqrt(denominator))
phi**** =  arc cos(-numerator / sqrt(denominator))
```

Find all candidates for every variation and take the one with maximum `f(phi)`. However, as mentioned, this approach is not suitable for large `n`. You need `2^n` variations of `f` and each variation requires `O(n^2)` time to construct the solution.

### Numerical solution

An alternative is a numerical optimization approach. The challenge is that your function is not convex. Hence, if you find a local maximum, you cannot say if it is the global one. Most algorithms require good initialization. You could find the initial point by sampling the domain of `phi` and picking the best one. Then, try some of the standard approaches (Newton, Levenberg-Marquardt, BFGS).

Comment: @Galactic Ketchup: Thanks for spotting the sin/cos mistake. For the other changes, please post an answer of your own since these would have changed the content of my answer quite a lot.

Comment: Super late, but in case anyone has a similar problem, you can try changing the ```abs``` function to a squared function (i.e. ```(li cos(phii + phi))²``` and it becomes much easier to differentiate. Btw, anyone know how to analytically maximize/minimize the real part of a complex number? Using ```l*cos(phi)``` means two variables...